# How does the sys.excepthook function work with PyQt5?

Tags: python, exception, pyqt, pyqt5, sys

I am working on a Python project which uses PyQt5 to create the GUI.  I was having an issue where errors wouldn't terminate the program or send error messages; the program would just crash.  While doing some research, I was able to find a snippet of code on Reddit that I added to my `__init__` method. This solved my problem, but unfortunately the post didn't really elaborate on the solution, so I am not sure why this works.

While reading through the Python documentation, I understand that the `sys.excepthook` function essentially obtains the exception, and prints it out to the console, is this correct?

It looks like this piece of code is obtaining the exception from `sys.excepthook` and storing it in variable `sys._excepthook`, then defining function `exception_hook` which essentially calls `sys.excepthook` (through `sys._excepthook`).

**My questions are:**

1) Why is this needed?  I understand that this is a known issue with PyQt where exceptions/error messages get "lost" and programs tend to crash.

2) How does this piece of code work to solve the problem?

```py
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    print(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.exit(1)

sys.excepthook = exception_hook
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sys.excepthook` is function called if exception occurs outside `try: .... except`. So if You would like to to manage it on your way You need to write own function.

In my Application I do not meet problem with lost error information, but such exception do not terminate application.

```py
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook # save original excepthook 

def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    print(exctype, value, traceback) # print exception. 
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback) # call original excepthoot. I do not why 
    sys.exit(1) # terminate program if above do not do this

sys.excepthook = exception_hook # overwrite default excepthook
```

If python 3 I suggest to change:

```py
import traceback
import sys 


def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    traceback_formated = traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, traceback)
    traceback_string = "".join(traceback_formated)
    print(traceback_string, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

there is also `sys.__excepthook__` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__excepthook__) which can be used.

Comment: I tried to edit this and then realised there were a lot of things I needed to change... so I tried to roll back to your original... please just reject my edits as I'm adding my own answer (based on yours)